# Unable to deploy application on EC2 instance using AWS CloudFormation template through cfn-init and UserData script

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam, user-data

I am trying to deploy sample.war application on EC2 instance at the time of launch. That is when an instance is launched the application should be deployed automatically on it using cfn-init and Metadata. I added a user with policy and authentication with no luck. If I wget with the S3 path, the file is being downloaded. Below is my script. What am I missing in this, or is there any other way to do this?

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Test QA Template
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: !Ref AMIIdParam
      InstanceType: !Ref InstanceType
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64: []
              tomcat: []
              httpd.x86_64: []
          services:
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
          files:
            /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample.zip:
              source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/sample.zip
              mode: '000500'
              owner: tomcat
              group: tomcat
              authentication: S3AccessCreds
      AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
        S3AccessCreds:
          type: 'S3'
          accessKeyId: !Ref HostKeys
          secretKey: Fn::GetAtt:
            - HostKeys
            - SecretAccessKey
          buckets: !Ref BucketName
  CfnUser:
    Type: AWS::IAM::User
    Properties:
      Path: '/'
      Policies:
        - PolicyName: 'S3Access'
          PolicyDocument:
           Statement:
             - Effect: 'Allow'
               Action: s3:*
               Resource: '*'
  HostKeys:
    Type: AWS::IAM::AccessKey
    Properties:
      UserName: !Ref CfnUser
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce this using the following template:

```
---
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Test QA Template
Resources:
  MyInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-08589eca6dcc9b39c
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      KeyName: default
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: !Sub |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          /opt/aws/bin/cfn-init -s ${AWS::StackId} --resource MyInstance --region ${AWS::Region}
    Metadata:
      AWS::CloudFormation::Init:
        config:
          packages:
            yum:
              java-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64: []
              tomcat: []
              httpd.x86_64: []
          services:
            sysvinit:
              httpd:
                enabled: true
                ensureRunning: true
          files:
            /usr/share/tomcat/webapps/sample.zip:
              source: https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/sample.zip
              mode: '000500'
              owner: tomcat
              group: tomcat
```

(In other words, use of the above template allowed me to install a sample.zip file using cfn-init.)

Thus there is something permissions-related in the way you're accessing the S3 bucket.

Suffice to say it is a bad practice to use Access Keys. Have a look at [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html) document on best practices of assigning an IAM Role to an EC2 instance and then adding a Bucket Policy that grants appropriate access to that Role.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this @Alex. I will surely try the approach specified in the document that you suggested.